# PowerShell Remove-Item return error even if set to SilentlyContinue

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script to execute a deployment of our application. At one point I want to delete a file to clean stuff up so I have this snippet :

```
try {
    # More code here
}
finally 
{
    if (Test-Path $tmpFile -PathType Leaf)  {
        Remove-Item $tmpFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        # I also tried to command from another Stack post, as shown in the PowerShell Screenshot
        # Remove-Item $tmpFile -EV Err -EA SilentlyContinue
    }
}
```

Two problems happen now... It says the file doesn't exist even though it does. (the `Test-Path` returned true). Also, the script doesn't continue even though it's set to `SilentlyContinue`.

I feel like the problem might be due to the shortpath, but PowerShell can resolve it with no issue.

[image]

Does anyone knows how to fix it so it can delete the file... or just not emit an error?

Answer (score 0):

Edit :
This is because of the TEMP directory location.

A better fix would be to change the path of the environment variable "TEMP" and "TMP" to something like `c:\temp`

Source :
https://superuser.com/questions/1524767/powershell-uses-the-short-8-3-form-for-envtemp

---

When I wrote this post, I thought that the issue might be the shortpath... so I decided to change my script like so :

```
finally 
{
    $fullTmpFile = (Get-Item -LiteralPath $tmpFile).FullName

    if (Test-Path $fullTmpFile -PathType Leaf)  {
        Remove-Item $fullTmpFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
}
```

And it's working perfectly. PowerShell and shortpath = bad.